# How to use HTML and CSS on a CMS Page?

Tags: javascript, css, cms, html

I have an e-commerce that runs Magento but we do not have the access to both code and server.

We want to create a new page to add some features like countdowns and a form for emails, but even adding all the code in the **"Content Area**", it still doesn't work.

**For example:** if I add `<script>test</script>` on the CMS Page editor and save, when accessing the page, it will just show `<script>test</script>` as if it is just a text and won't do the action that was supposed to do (in my case, show a countdown). Even with the correct tags and everything else, it just appears to be a text that was written.

So, how do I create a page with HTML, CSS and Script that works correctly on CMS Pages on Magento?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems like you are using `<script>` tag in wrong way. Because it doesn't print or alert anything if you write `<script>test</script>` in CMS page.

**JS Fiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/b8Lgvtap/

**For javascript code**

```
<script>
    var now = new Date();
    alert(now); // it will alert current date and time
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'current date and time - ' + now;
</script>
```

**For HTML code**

```
<div id="countdown">Count Down Start</div>
```

**For style** you can use `<style>` tag

```
<style>
 #countdown{ 
    display:inline;
    color: red !important; 
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, Abhishek!

I've added your code directly on the CMS Page (just adjusted the CSS to be inline) and it worked!

Now I just need to implement the counter to count from today to a specific date on the script.

Comment: please check this answer and JS fiddle code. I did the exactly same thing which you want. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189201/countdown-timer/189202 - hope it helps :) please accept the answer of its useful :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution to put your **CSS**, **JS** only in your cms page is to add a custom path css, js on it via xml like this :

Go to : `admin CMS -> Pages -> Design -> XML Layout Update`then add the code bellow

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/filename.js</name></action> 
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/filename.css</name><params/></action>
</reference>
```

[image]

Then you add your css code in `skin/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/css/filename.css`

you add your js code in `skin/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/js/filename.js`

Comment: Hello, Prince! Thanks for your answer.

As I said, I do not have access to add archives on the server. So this way is not possible for me.

I need to found a way where I can do everything just in the CMS Page Editor or at least, call a JS that is uploaded on another server.

Comment: @magflok I gave you the best way to do that and according the standards of Magento, if you haven't access to your server it's another problem.